# Extract each data frame name from a list of data frames in lapply function

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have a list of many data frames and I am trying to perform manipulations to each data frame in the list. I created this lapply function and then the list is then merged together. However when trying to rename certain columns so that they include the respective data frame name:

```
paste(deparse(substitute(x)),"_start"
```

the dataframe names are being extracted like this :

```
x[[i]]_start_1
```

Here is the full code:

```
df_list <-lapply(df_list, function(x){
  lookup <- c(start = paste(deparse(substitute(x)),"_start"),
              end = paste(deparse(substitute(x)),"_end"),
              top = paste(deparse(substitute(x)),"_top"),
              left = paste(deparse(substitute(x)),"_left"),
              height = paste(deparse(substitute(x)),"_height"),
              width = paste(deparse(substitute(x)),"_width"),
              type = paste(deparse(substitute(x)),"_type"),
              value = paste(deparse(substitute(x)),"_value"))
  x <- x %>% rename_with(.fn = ~lookup[.x], .cols = intersect(names(.), names(lookup)))
  x <- arrange(x, creativeId)
  x <- x[,-1]
  x <- x %>% distinct()
  x$counter <- with(x, ave(creativeId, with(rle(creativeId), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)), FUN = seq_along))
  x <- x %>% relocate(counter)
  x <- x %>% pivot_wider(names_from =counter, values_from= -names(.)[1:2])
}) 

new_df <- Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,all=TRUE), df_list)
```

Please let me know if there is a workaround so that the data frame names are printed correctly. Thank you!

Comment: I would use `Map` instead of `lapply` here, i..e. `Map(function(x, nm) {.... }, df_list, names(df_list))` and rename with the list name using `nm`

Comment: I get an error here: Error in `purrr:::stop_bad_type()`:
! `.x` must be a vector, not a function

Comment: I guess you created `lookup <- c(start = paste0(nm, "_start"), ..)`

Comment: This is working fine for me `lookup <- c(mpg = 'mpg_1', cyl = 'cyl_1', hello = 'hello_1');
head(mtcars) %>% rename_with(.fn = ~lookup[.x], .cols = intersect(names(.), names(lookup)))`

Comment: Yes, i think it is a problem with the function coming directly after Map. map(function(x,nm)) . I tried map(df_list, names(df_list), function(x, nm) {....} but that does not seem to work either.

Comment: The function I used is `Map` and not `map` (which is from purrr)

Comment: Try the code in the solution posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `Map`

```
df_list2 <- Map(function(x, nm) {
lookup <- c(start = paste0(nm,"_start"),
              end = paste0(nm, "_end"),
              top = paste0(nm,"_top"),
              left = paste0(nm,"_left"),
              height = paste0(nm,"_height"),
              width = paste0(nm,"_width"),
              type = paste0(nm,"_type"),
              value = paste0(nm,"_value"))
  x <- x %>% 
    rename_with(.fn = ~lookup[.x], .cols = intersect(names(.), names(lookup)))
  x <- arrange(x, creativeId)
  x <- x[,-1]
  x <- x %>% distinct()
  x$counter <- with(x, ave(creativeId, 
   with(rle(creativeId), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)), FUN = seq_along))
  x <- x %>% relocate(counter)
  x <- x %>% pivot_wider(names_from =counter, values_from= -names(.)[1:2])
    

}, df_list, names(df_list))
```